# Using "native" wat/wasm function in smart-contract

Tags: smart-contract, wasm

I have to do some heavy computation in my smart-contract, like say `a+b`. Fortunately, I have written some very efficient implementation in "native" (web)assembly, like:

File `add.wast`:

```
(module
 (func $add (export "add_asm")
    (param $x i32) 
    (param $y i32) 
    (result i32) 

    (i32.add (get_local $x) (get_local $y))
  ) 
)
```

The question is how I can use it in smartcontract? I tried (without luck) something like:

file `math.cpp`:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

int add_asm(int a, int b);

using namespace eosio;
class math : public eosio::contract {
  public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]]
      void add( int a, int b ) {
            int res = add_asm(a,b);
            print(res);
      }
};

EOSIO_ABI( math, (add) )
```

And:

```
$ make
eosio-wast2wasm -r add.wast -o add.wasm
eosio-cpp -c math.cpp -o math.o
eosio-ld add.wasm math.o -o math
/usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/wasm-ld: error: math.o: undefined symbol: add_asm(int, int)
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'math' failed
```

Is there any way to use webassembly in smart-contract?

Best,

PS. 
To make the picture complete, here is the `Makefile`:

```
wat := $(wildcard *.wast)
wasm := $(patsubst %.wast,%.wasm,$(wat))
objs := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))

all: math

math: $(wasm) $(objs)
    eosio-ld $(wasm) $(objs) -o $@

$(objs): %.o: %.cpp
    eosio-cpp -c $< -o $@

$(wasm): %.wasm: %.wast
    eosio-wast2wasm -r $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.wasm *.o verify *~
```

Comment: Would be interesting to know! I was trying to use wasm files on the web site, so I can share my code with the smart contract and the front end.

Comment: Any news on this? Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, the final linking stage of the compiler pulls different wasm modules together, so you could include your own wasm code in a module and then link it at that stage.

However, this isn't supported by block.one and might not be possible at some future time.

If you succeed, please share the code and build structure that you used, it would be interesting for many people I believe.

---

## Source

Telegram, EOS Developers channel (https://t.me/joinchat/Esi1OkPktgcFeJ3Lmlcrqg)

> Todd Fleming, [11.01.19 15:16] [In reply to Phillip Hamnett - EOS42]
> There isn't a asm directive, but the final link stage pulls wasm
> modules together. You could include a non-C++ wasm in the mix
>
> Todd Fleming, [11.01.19 15:17] Note that isn't a supported path and
> may disappear in the future
>
> Matt Witherspoon, [11.01.19 15:17] [In reply to Todd Fleming] I've had
> trouble doing that. Unless there is a bunch of magic sections lld
> won't link them
>
> Matt Witherspoon, [11.01.19 15:18] And I don't know of a way to
> generate those magic sections
>
> Matt Witherspoon, [11.01.19 15:21] at the llvm layer I believe there
> actually is an asm directive even for wasm. but I don't know if that
> is plumbed through clang